# Rotate label by variable angle in polar plot

Tags: gnuplot

I plotted many points with labels in an polar coordinate system. Now I want to rotate the labels in the tangential direction. So I have to rotate

- a point plotted at t=0, r=arbitrary by 0 degrees,
- a point plotted at t=pi/2, r=arbitrary by 90 degrees,
- a point plotted at t=pi, r=arbitrary by 180 degrees and so on.

I found the 'rotate by' function here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/textrotate.html

But only fixed values for the rotate angle are possible.
I thought about sth. like:

```
plot 'point-data.dat'  using ($1/360*2*pi):($2):($1) with labels rotate by variable font "arial,8"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, that isn't possible with gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing and found a "workaround" to do this. It is not perfect but it worked in my case:
You can do many plots in a loop and assign a different text angle for each plot:

data file data.txt:

```
#alpha  r   label   rotation
0   1   text1   10
.2  1   text2   20
.4  1   text3   30
.6  1   text4   40
.8  1   text5   50
1   1   text6   60
```

Plotting commands:

```
isequal(x1,x2,x3)=(x1==x2?x3:1/0)
setonly(x1,x2,x3)=((x1==x2)?roto=x3:1/0)
set polar
plot for [k=0:7] "data.txt" u (isequal(($0),k,($1))):((setonly( ($0),k,($4) )*0.0)+($2)):3 w labels rotate by roto
```